# Calculate Product of length of lists in dataframe and store in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe, whose values are lists. How can I calculate product of lengths of all lists in a row, and store in a separate column? Maybe the following example will make it clear:

```
test_1 = ['Protocol', 'SCADA', 'SHM System'] 
test_2 = ['CM', 'Finances']
test_3 = ['RBA', 'PBA']

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[test_1,test_2,test_3],'b':[test_2]*3, 'c':[test_3]*3, 'product of len(lists)':[12,8,8]})
```

This is a sample code which shows that in first row, the product is 3 * 2 * 2 = 12 which are lengths of each list in first row...and simlarly for other rows.
How can I compute these products and store in a new column, for a dataframe whose all values are lists?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and [`DataFrame.product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.product.html):

```
df['product of len(lists)'] = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].applymap(len).product(axis=1)
```

[out]

```
                              a               b           c  product of len(lists)
0  [Protocol, SCADA, SHM System]  [CM, Finances]  [RBA, PBA]                     12
1                 [CM, Finances]  [CM, Finances]  [RBA, PBA]                      8
2                     [RBA, PBA]  [CM, Finances]  [RBA, PBA]                      8
```